# Invalid Prisma Invocation:

Tags: next.js, prisma

This API already worked with Thunder Client, API client,with a body`{"name":"test"}` but don't work with code in backend.tsx

**/api/language/index.ts**

```
async function handlePost(req:NextApiRequest,res:NextApiResponse){
  try{
    const { name }= await req.body;

    if (!name) throw new Error("invalid "+name);

    const languageData = await prisma.language.findUnique({
      where:{
        name: data.name
      }
    })
    if (languageData){
      return res.status(400).json({
        error:"Language already exists"
      })
    }
    else{
      const result = await prisma.language.create({
        data: {
          name: data.name
        }
      })
      return res.status(200).end();
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: err.message
    })
  }
}
```

**backend.tsx**

```
async function postLang(dataName){
 fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/language", {
  method:"POST",
  body:JSON.stringify({name:dataName})})
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res=>console.log(res))
```

**error**

Invalid `prisma.language.findUnique()` invocation:

{
where: {
?   name?: String,
?   id?: Int
}
}

Argument where of type LanguageWhereUniqueInput needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.

Note: Lines with ? are optional.

**schema.prisma**

```
model Language {
  id      Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String              @unique
  project LanguageOnProject[]
}

model LanguageOnProject {
  project      Project  @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  projectId    Int
  language     Language @relation(fields: [languageName], references: [name])
  languageName String // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  assignedAt   DateTime @default(now())

  @@id([projectId, languageName])
}
```

Comment: What would you get if you `console.log(data.name)`?

Comment: @Danila it should be `{name:"examplename"}`  but it is `undefined`

Comment: So this is the error then. Argument for `findUnique` cannot be undefined

Comment: Exactly but the point is I use a normal fetching with "POST" method and i already tried with a client. but I still got an error.

Comment: How can you get this error with this check `if (!name)`? If you have this check then you would not get this Prisma error, right? And if so then your question is solved? If you have some other problems you should probably create another question, because this one is not related to Prisma anymore?